# Laravel redirects to 404 error page if URL has www prefix

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I'm having project in Laravel 6.12. I've hosted my app in live server and having SSL configured.

It works well when I access with https://example.com, but when I try to access with https://www.example.com it shows laravel's default 404 error page.

It means, it is accessing the project directory, loading css, js etc but showing 404 error page.

my .htaccess has following lines

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,QSA,L]
```

Could anyone help to get rid of this?

Comment: Check `VirtualHost` config for `www.example.com`. Make sure it is same as `example.com`.

Comment: What do you exactly want?
To redirect it to non-www or serve it as it is

Comment: @akbansa yes, I want www to non-www path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your .htaccess with this 
if try https://example.com it will force redirect to https://www.example.com
This is true to SEO

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
# check if not have www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# force redirect to www
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```